# Problem with div element jumping up a few pixels in JQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the latest version of JQuery and trying to animate a div to the left of the screen. It's just about fine, except that it jumps up noticeably before actually animating. I've set it up in jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ns6string/agY2z/
Be sure to click on either 'portfolio' or 'about' to see what I'm dealing with.

You can see the code I've set up (I tried to clean it up) but here it is again, in case anyone doesn't feel like hitting the jump ;)

HTML:

```
<body>
        <div id="header">
        HOME
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="portfolio">
                <h3 class="menuitem" >Portfolio</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="about">
                <h3 id="about" class="menuitem">About</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{ right: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; top: 0px; position: fixed; color: #444444; margin: 0px; background-color: #c7c7c7; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
#menu{ text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px white; position: fixed; margin-top:220px; width: 200px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; right: auto; left: 47.5%; }
.menuitem{ display: inline-block; text-align: left; }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Hovering stuff went here, shouldn't be relevant


    $(".menuitem").click(function() {
        $("#menu").animate({
            'top': '10%',
            'left': '7%'
        }, {
            duration: 500,
            queue: false
        }, function() {})
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: Very odd issue.

All you need to do is specify a css value for `top: 5%` on `#menu` (should be fine with any value if 5% is not what you want). This will stop the "shake" when you click it.

On a side note I noticed that you've specified values for `right` and `left`. I would suggest removing the `right` value.

Comment: looks like initializing the top was key. and the right value was a leftover from something else I forgot to remove. Thanks!